# Create List view to display category totals

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a list of tickets and there age:

|---**Ticket ID**---|---**Age (days)**---|
|--- WO#12 ---|-------- 35 -------|
|--- WO#13 ---|-------- 70 -------|
|--- WO#14 ---|-------- 99 -------|

I need to create a list view that will display the data like this:

|---**Ticket Age**---|---**Ticket Count**---|
|--- > 30 days ---|--(count here) ---|
|--- > 60 days ---|--(count here) ---|
|--- > 90 days ---|--(count here) ---|

Is there any possible way to create this kind of view? I want to count the number of tickets greater than 30 days old, greater than 60, and greater than 90. I have been searching for hours and I can't find any way possible. I need this to also be used as a data source for a chart.

Comment: Can you use rdlc report, if yes... You can simple make a DataSource with a DataTable and fill DataTable with code and provide .rdlc report as dynamic source! In .rdlc you can use chart --- but this is a coding solution, we mostly jump to .rdlc reports if OOB is not helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noobie mistake >_<. I figured out that all I needed was to add a calculated column to my original table with a formula of:

=IF(TotalDaysOpen<30,"< 30 days",
IF(AND([TotalDaysOpen]>=30,[TotalDaysOpen]<60),"30-<60 days",
IF(AND([TotalDaysOpen]>=60,[TotalDaysOpen]<90),"60-<90 days","90 days+")))

|---Ticket ID---|---Age (days)----|---AgeCategory---|
|--- WO#12 ---|-------- 35 -------|---- < 30 -------|
|--- WO#13 ---|-------- 70 -------|---- 30-60-------|
|--- WO#14 ---|-------- 99 -------|---- 60-90-------|

With that, I could easily bind the list data to a chart. I didn't realize you could have such complex formulae in a calculated column

Answer (score 0):

You can have three different list views.

1. You can have one view called "30 days" that will filter all the "Ticket Age" that is greater than or equal to '30' and less than '60' and then at the bottom just include the "Count" in the ID filter. That will show you the count of the amount in that view.
2. Make another just like it called "60 days" that will filter all the "Ticket Age" that is greater than or equal to '60' and less than '90'
3. Make yet another just like it called "90 days" that will filter all the "Ticket Age" that is greater than or equal to '90'

Comment: I thought about this, but is it possible to have 3 different views as a data source in a chart? I tried to see if I could use each view for a different series in a single chart, but I could not figure out how

Comment: that depends on what kind of chart you are using...? Using the sharepoint 2010 chart web part you should be able to filter the list based on your needs like you would with a list view. Check out the chart web part info page: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-a-chart-by-using-the-chart-web-part-HA101889211.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA101889216

Comment: I have tried that but I don't see any way to make it display all 3 views in the same chart :(